# Power Shell script to get remote server certificates

Tags: powershell, ssl, server, remote-access

I have over 200 servers and I am using this script to get the SSL certificates on each server. However, I am looking to get the info from each server and export to a csv.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path cert:\LocalMachine\My, cert:\LocalMachine\WebHosting `
  -SSLServerAuthentication | Where-Object -FilterScript {((Get-Date))} | format-list -Property PSPath,FriendlyName,NotAfter
```

I thought of adding adding this to the top of script

```
$remotecomputers = "Server_Name","Server_Name","Server_Name"
```

Comment: What isn't working currently? Also, are you testing the script on your local machine? (It may behave differently when accessing remote machines.)

Comment: `Invoke-Command` accepts an array of computers, so you would just have to pipe to `Export-Csv`. The only issue I see is, you'd have to remove `Formart-List` first.

Comment: The first script I wrote works just fine. I am asking what script do I need to place in front of my script to get the certificates for all my servers.